# npm and bower updates fail majority of the time depending on the network

Tags: git, npm, bower

I am having issues both with bower and npm when I perform `npm update`.

```
jrquick$ npm update
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[PRIVATE_PROJECT]/[PRIVATE_REPOSITORY].git) ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[PRIVATE_PROJECT]/[PRIVATE_REPOSITORY].git) fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[PRIVATE_PROJECT]/[PRIVATE_REPOSITORY].git) 
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[PRIVATE_PROJECT]/[PRIVATE_REPOSITORY].git) Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[PRIVATE_PROJECT]/[PRIVATE_REPOSITORY].git) and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git fetch -a origin
npm ERR! ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jrquick/[PRIVATE_PROJECT]/[PRIVATE_REPOSITORY]/npm-debug.log
```

When running from my work's network connection it fails with this error a majority of them time. However, I can go to Starbucks or my apartment and run the same command successfully.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I do not have any control over the network but I thought maybe changing packet sizes or some type of setting within git or npm to avoid this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that bitbucket has blocked your work IP address?

Comment: No. I never have issues with git commands; clone, pull, etc. it only happens at my office, said the more npm dependencies than the more likely it occurs. Which makes me think the network is losing a packet or timeout possibly. But like I said, works at my home network.

Comment: Does your workplace have a lot of people doing `npm update`? If so, you could be getting throttled. Do you notice that the error occurs only with bitbucket repositories?

Comment: Not necessarily. I am one of two engineers in the entire department. But it is a university so with employees, students and faculty it is possible

Comment: Oh yeah, it's likely that the university has very few public facing IPs. I wouldn't be surprised if this were the issue. If the situation isn't consistent, and only occurs on one network, this is my guess. If it fails 100% of the time, it's probably something else.

Comment: it only happens at your university, or office because they have a FASTER connection, overwhelming the git server more easily, gitlab, github and bitbucket all throttle connections, just slow down the network and you will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a throttle issue, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326527/npm-and-bower-updates-fail-majority-of-the-time-depending-on-the-network/43533874#comment74114805_43326527) by [John D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437270/john-d), the theoretical solution (as mentioned in "[GitLab, NPM, and SSHd MaxStartups](http://lukewaite.github.io/gitlab/npm/ssh/2015/08/17/gitlab-npm-ssh-woes.html)") would be to increase the `MaxStartups` value of the `sshd` configuration of the server.

Since it is bitbucket.org, you don't have access to that configuration, of course.

Another workaround would be to see if the issue persists when using https instead of ssh (and using automatically your credentials, cached by a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials))

```
git config --global url."https://bitbucket.org/".insteadOf git@bitbucket.org:
```

Comment: This appears to have worked for the most part. I used `git config --global url."https://bitbucket.org/".insteadOf ssh://git@bitbucket.org/` (slight difference) and then set up my credentials with `git credential-osxkeychain` and `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this by slowing down my network connection while building. (on a mac you can do this with the "Network Link Conditioner" from Apple.

a long term solution is to use your own npm instance and change those settings on your server.

npm could be fixed to deal with this, at least via a configurable option, but the cause is github, gitlab etc who aren't expecting so many concurrent calls to their server, its debatable if they should throttle connections like this.